Why does Russia strike electric power in Ukraine?
It's become a common refrain to hear of Russia's strikes against electric power infrastructure in Ukraine.
Each iteration always seems to be the biggest yet, and the media is always keen to report it (as a self-evident horror of war, or massive spectacle).
It's easy to imagine that the lights going off imposes a general inconvenience on an enemy's economy, but I find it hard to believe that the general population of Ukraine would be seriously demoralised by occasional power cuts. If anything it might increase in-person social contact and solidarity, and promote resilience (assuming there is real support for the war in the first place).
For a free-standing enemy, attacking their energy infrastructure might also stop their arms factories and war economy, with obvious military implications at the fronts. But Ukraine is propped up and supplied by the West, so their internal economy could be completely destroyed without it necessarily halting Ukraine at the fronts.
And with repeated rounds of destruction, Ukraine will presumably take steps to increase resilience or minimise downtime for the most militarily important energy uses.
What's the military function of these strikes from Russia's perspective? Is there any substantial function at all?

I think that's a false premise that Ukraine's allies will supply it indefinitely, absent an economy of its own.

@alamar, there's no reason Ukraine should be absent an economy of its own, if the West constantly inject capital equipment to replenish all war damage. Averaged across the entire West and secured with Ukrainian assets to be looted after the war, I doubt the costs are large - I mean, what does a new substation or a diesel generator cost compared to the hi-tech missiles Russia uses to destroy them?

@Steve, You should calculate the number of "diesel generators" that are needed to replenish the energy deficit, and what amount of fuel you need to transport and distribute. Also, add maintenance costs. And THEN compare it to the cost of a missile. Also, don't forget about https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_energy_crisis_(2021–2023) — despite the date range in the title, it's not over yet

Well it's an attack on the civilian population and thus bordering war crimes if not already that. In case of attacks on nuclear power plants it's also a major health and environmental issue which might involve even outsiders of the war so basically a nuke that is already deployed.
Also you think about military production, but energy is also used for civilian production. Not to mention that there are facilities where the power source MUST NOT be interrupted, for example hospitals, control centers for flights, railways etc just to name some (Thanks to Joe W for the implicit but rather obvious example of refrigerators!). Sure they have emergency supply, but the emergency shouldn't be all the time either...
So having the lights go out might not just be a minor inconvenience but might cause actual problems and as said largely for the civilian population. As said the "ingenious" approach of demoralizing the civilian population is always bordering a war crime. But even if it's your own side doing it as some "strategic decision to inhibit the military supply of the enemy", it doesn't take much to realize how insidious that is.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Calling attacks on civilian infrastructure "war crimes" only dilutes the term. E.g. on one hand you have the Bucha massacre, and on the other hand you have blackouts. You call both "war crimes", then Eugene points out that Serbia also had blackouts back in 1999, and suddenly both conflicts start to look comparable in terms of cruelty and injustice.

@DmitryGrigoryev Vandalism and murder are both crimes, does calling vandalism a crime dilute the term and makes murder look less severe? I don't think so. I think it's the other way around by downplaying crimes if they are not the most severe, you make them look more acceptable when that already is stepping over a line.

"does calling vandalism a crime dilute the term and makes murder look less severe?" - yes, I think so. E.g. if I argue that criminals should not be allowed to work at a bank or live next door to a school, and you give an example of a criminal who tagged a phone booth while still in college, my argument does look weaker.

@DmitryGrigoryev That's making MY argument, not yours, as in "yes just because they are both crimes (though not sure vandalism isn't still a misdemeanor or something like that, so short of a crime in the legal sense (1+ year prison), but a "crime" in the colloquial sense (punishable by law)) doesn't mean they are necessarily comparable". All that being a "crime" in the colloquial sense means is that it's a deed that passed the threshold of "shit happens" and went into "we got to do something about it". That the something should be in relation to the severity of the crime is clear.

@DmitryGrigoryev 2/ I didn't touch upon that before, but "blackouts" also makes these attacks sound more harmless than they are. Like apparently you think of "ok a few hours without TV and gaming, not great not the end of the world". But what it also means is production shortages, hospitals and critical infrastructure without energy (emergency generators aren't to run constant), lack of heating in winter, water pipes might burst, refrigerators not working, which could lead to food spoilage, diseases, famines. So even though not direct murder that can kill people or make them severely suffer.

@DmitryGrigoryev 3/ Also do you actually think that it would deter the trolls and bad faith actors from making comparisons or justifying war crimes if you'd redraw the line? Like essentially the purpose in drawing such a line is to mark a point where you say "too much harm". If you set it late you allow a lot of harm before you consider it a problem, if you set it early you can end up having too many criminals and too few law enforcement. But to argue that an already severe case is too early because you could act much worse is likely not what you're looking for, is it?

I'm fully aware that blackouts mean much more than no TV, as you can see in my answer here. More to the point, I don't understand what you mean by "too early". Perhaps an example would help: @Eugene mentions blackouts in Serbia in 1999, is it "too early" to call them war crimes?

@DmitryGrigoryev https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-63754808 Also it wouldn't be the first time either that the U.S. would have resorted to war crimes and morally dubious battle tactics whether they are legal or not and calling that out is also fair. You can still set them in proper comparison to other war crimes without having to deny they are crimes or at least morally dubious in the first place.

Electrical capacity, like other forms of infrastructure, is a necessity for a properly functioning industrial base. Damage to infrastructure makes it hard for material, people, and necessities to be produced and move from place to place.  Electricity, in specific, is key to communications - particularly communications between civilian actors, including the defense sector employees needed for manufacturing and so on.
A defender's ability to offer resistance to an invader is predicated on that defender being able to see, hear, eat, and stay warm.  Civilian eyes and ears, in particular, are blacked out when the grid doesn't function properly.  Without a ubiquitous supply of electricity, a kid on his bike who spots a column moving through the next neighborhood can't just pick up a phone and report it.  (Just because you have a flashlight, doesn't mean the lights being out offers no impediment to the ease of your operations within the room.)
Just because your opponent has an answer to the impairment (resilience of energy grid design), doesn't mean you leave a target intact.  Resilient energy grids are expensive, backups are a form of logistical overhead, and every truck compensating for an electric train that can't haul goods is a truck NOT being used to bring ammo to the front.
You are correct that Ukraine has answers to most of the effects that impairment of their electrical grid inflicts, but as an attacker, Russia very much wants to force Ukraine to activate those answers and spend the resources doing so - so that those resources can't be directed towards repelling the invaders.
Contrary to others' opinions, this does not constitute a war crime (not that Russia hasn't likely committed numerous, but infrastructure attacks are not prima facie war crimes by themselves), even though civilian suffering is the least likely to be mitigated.  The laws of war require that selected targets bring military benefit in a manner that economizes on civilian harm (i.e. that militaries choose the means to achieve those military benefits that cause the least harm to civilians, among those means that accomplish the stated objective), and that those military benefits are at least proportional to the harm inflicted (itself a highly subjective estimate and one that is - as is almost everything in law of war matters - context-driven).
For this reason, infrastructure attacks are often highly favored. Blowing up power stations is less likely to involve mass civilian casualties because power stations are very equipment heavy, have safety concerns of their own which cause them to be located a minimum safe distance from dense urban centers, and their technical complexity means you wreck a lot of bucks for your bang.
Russia's been up to a bunch of highly questionable stuff in this invasion, but attacking electricity grids is actually pretty de rigueur for modern warfare.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Because it's previously been demonstrated to be effective. E.g. Serbia capitulated in the 1999 Kossovo War, soon after it's electrical infrastructure started getting hit hard:

Only during the last two weeks of Allied Force, however, did NATO
finally strike with real determination against Serbia’s electrical
power generating capability, a target set that had been attacked in
Baghdad from the very first days of Desert Storm. The earlier “soft”
attacks at the beginning of May with graphite filament bombs against
the transformer yards of Yugoslavia’s main power grid had caused a
temporary disruption of the power supply by shorting out transformers
and disabling them rather than destroying them. But this time, in
perhaps the single most attention-getting strike of the entire air war
up to that point, the Yugoslav electrical grid was severely damaged
over the course of three consecutive nights starting on May
24. Those attacks, directed against electrical power facilities and related targets in Belgrade, Novi Sad, and Nis, the three largest
cities in Serbia, shut off the power to 80 percent of Serbia, leaving
millions without electricity or water service. They affected the heart
of Yugoslavia’s IADS, as well as the computers that ran its banking
system and other important national consumers of electricity. As
evidence that these infrastructure attacks were making their effects
felt, the early street dancing and carefully orchestrated
demonstrations of studied outrage against NATO in response to its
earlier pinprick attacks became displaced by a manifest weariness on
the part of most residents


with the possibility that electrical power and water supplies to
Belgrade might be cut off at any time, the approach of winter offered
the prospect of making daily life horrendously difficult for Serbia’s
leaders and rank and file alike

This is directly from an official RAND assessment of the air war:
https://www.rand.org/content/dam/rand/pubs/monograph_reports/MR1365/RAND_MR1365.pdf
During both Gulf wars, Iraq's electrical grid was also hit pretty hard and effectively.
Now, Ukraine isn't in the same position as Serbia back then, in terms of being cut off from external support, but since the question is about why, the same reasoning as the above cases is being applied.

I don't know if the Russian military has published doctrinal documents that discuss this in some detail (like the US has), but at the level of declarations from the top, at least in April 2024 Putin was quoted saying:

"The strikes on energy are linked in part with solving one of the tasks we set for ourselves, and that is demilitarisation. We believe above all that in this way we will affect Ukraine's military industrial complex and in a very direct way."
Russia, he said, had refrained from carrying out such attacks in winter "out of humanitarian considerations".
"What I mean is that we didn't want to leave social institutions without power, hospitals and the like," he said. But he said the Ukrainian strikes -- mainly on oil refineries in many different Russian regions in recent weeks -- prompted Moscow to respond.

I don't want to write too much commentary of my own here, but the latter part of the quote (which is just paraphrased) points to this also being [or at least claimed to be] a tit-for-tat response [at least to some degree], or "escalation dominance" to borrow/apply a term from Western analysts/theoreticians.
Back in Dec 2022, the NYT commented that:

Russia’s aerial attacks on Ukraine’s energy infrastructure escalated sharply in October as Moscow sustained a series of battlefield losses that military experts say thwarted its push to capture Ukraine’s entire Black Sea coast and the whole of the eastern Donbas region.

FM Lavrov was also asked about these attacks back then, but he was somewhat less direct and just said that

Russia is hitting targets that are used to replenish Ukrainian forces with weapons provided by Western nations and that the Ukrainian forces rely on to operate.

(as the NYT paraphrased him.)
More recently though (Aug. 26, 2024):

Russia said on Monday it had conducted a massive strike on Ukraine which it said had disrupted the electricity supply and the transport by rail of arms and ammunition to the front line.
Russia's Defence Ministry said in a statement it had fired missiles from the air and sea and that it had struck electricity substations in nine Ukrainian regions and gas compressor stations in three regions.
"This morning the armed forces of the Russian Federation launched a massive strike with long-range air- and sea-based precision weapons, and with operational and tactical aviation and unmanned aerial vehicles against critical energy infrastructure facilities supporting the work of Ukraine's military-industrial complex," the ministry said.

So they seem to be linking these attacks with disrupting the Ukrainian rail network, at least more recently.

I don't want to make this into a [long] discussion about the war crimes angle (because the OP's Q is how Russia justifies these), but it's perhaps worth mentioning that the ICC has indicted some Russian commanders for alleged excessive attacks on civilian infrastructure [in two 'rounds' in fact]. OTOH they also did that with Israeli leaders, and while the US applauded the first move, they criticized the latter. (AFAICT, the Court has not yet actually issued any warrants in the latter case but they did in the former.) The attacks on the electrical energy infrastructure in Ukraine were specifically mentioned in the ICC press releases.

Needless to say, Russia also attack energy infrastructure in winter with apparently full knowledge of what that entails ... https://www.google.com/search?q=russia+attacks+ukraine+energy+infrastructure&sca_esv=861bfe30a48f43f8&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A12%2F1%2F2023%2Ccd_max%3A3%2F1%2F2024&tbm=

As I've said before, Putin entered this conflict as a prestige war, not a purposive war. He wasn't looking for (and was not prepared for) a full-scale military conflict. He was operating on the 'bully' premise that weaker people will cave under a menacing attitude and a swift punch in the arm, and I believe he honestly thought that his initial invasion would scatter Ukrainian forces and collapse the Ukrainian government in a matter of days, leaving him to bask in glory with little actual cost or effort.
By the way, this is not something unique to Putin. For instance, W. Bush fell into the same ego-trap in Iraq, another prestige war. 'Mission Accomplished' my you-know-what…
At any rate, Putin has never moved past the 'prestige' aspect of this war, nor the 'bully' mindset that accompanies it. One of the key features of that mindset is that any act of disrespect from 'weaker' entities must be met with punishment that is as swift and brutal as possible without crossing any normative lines (the bully craves respect, and cannot allow himself to be seen a weak or abnormal). The war itself is a slow grind, and likely deeply uninteresting to Putin (who seems only to demand achievements without regard to tactics or cost). But when Ukraine does something surprising, unsettling, or brilliant on the battlefield, Putin's knee-jerk response is to launch long-range and somewhat haphazard attacks on Ukrainian civilian infrastructure. These are not meant to be strategic or even tactical actions. They are a quick jab meant to punish the Ukrainian people for making Putin feel stupid, weak, or inferior.

Correct to some extent: "The two sides at one point were actually negotiating through Qatar for a halt to such strikes [on energy infra] until the talks were derailed by Ukraine’s incursion into Russia in early August." https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/2024/08/26/ukraine-russia-strikes-kyiv-blackouts/
And the first big wave of such strikes was in similar 'surprise' circumstances in 2022. OTOH, one could also say that Russia decided to go for those once they realized that the war won't be over quickly, so a more WW2-like approach is warranted, in this respect. (Not my DV.)

@MakeStackExchangeGREAT4ever Pootin's linking Kursk to this agreement actually shows how they respect their own words - if it were agreed energy for energy, I don't see how Kursk has anything to do with it. Assuming they mentioned Kursk - as it is the WP who did, it is very likely, that anything else would trigger voiding this agreement when they felt like it if Kursk didn't happen. This aside, their actions indirectly confirm Ted's suggestion it is a war of prestige for pootin - from their view, Ukraine did something to lower the ratings badly, so, they must be punished hard and swiftly.


I find it hard to believe that the general population of Ukraine would be seriously demoralised by occasional power cuts. If anything it might increase in-person social contact and solidarity, and promote resilience (assuming there is real support for the war in the first place).

You might underestimate the effect of these power cuts. It's very easy to sit in your chair and support the war if it doesn't affect you directly (I imagine this is true for the vast majority of people reading SE). But if there is some direct impact, directly via death of loved ones or indirectly via power cuts, then after sufficiently long periods of it, you might shift your stance. Attacking the power grid has the effect of bringing the war to everyone in Ukraine, including those who live in towns with no military value and therefore do not suffer direct attacks.
Electrical power pervades daily life to such an extent that losing it, even for short periods, can be extremely inconvenient. Imagine living on the 8th floor of a building and finding you have to take the stairs for example (even worse if you're returning with groceries). Or trying to live without air conditioning in a heatwave. Even if you can, your dependents might not be able to.
Search out some sources for living under these conditions. Example.

Power supply is a matter of life and death for Tetiana's son.
He was born with disabilities, and needs electricity-powered equipment to be able to breathe, to eat, and to receive medication.
...
Tetiana, who lives in the southern port city of Odesa, says that the endless power cuts make life extremely difficult because she needs to make sure the supply of electricity is constant.
She has a generator which runs on petrol and needs to be topped up all the time, but it has to be stopped every six hours to cool down.
Power cuts also affect mobile phone coverage, so getting through to the ambulance service for her son can be a struggle too.
"Sometimes it takes half an hour, sometimes it's an hour before the ambulance arrives when my child goes into convulsions and turns blue,” she says. “My son can die if he doesn't get oxygen. I'm lost for words.”

Suffer through years of this and you might well change your mind on whether the war is worth fighting. Like yeah, it's about freedom and liberty and Russian barbarism and all that, but is it worth the life of your baby?
One can see the impact of this in Ukraine already - some Ukrainians are even willing to live under a Russian flag if it means peace; furthermore,  polls indicate that the proportion of Ukrainians willing to cede land for peace has increased substantially since 2022, with most recent data putting it at 1/3 of all respondents. If the current trend continues, it might soon reach a majority.

"but is it worth the life of your baby" Ukrainians can also move abroad. Europe still welcomes them, at least as temp refugees. True, some might not be inclined to take that step or rather regret it. https://www.voanews.com/a/some-ukrainians-living-in-us-want-to-go-home-/7751159.html

@MakeStackExchangeGREAT4ever that's not possible for males between the ages of 18 and 60 - and some females might not want to move abroad without their partners.

More direct link to the poll graphs https://kiis.com.ua/?lang=eng&cat=reports&id=1421&page=1

I don't understand why allies aren't massively shipping balcony solar power stations (800 Wp) with battery storage to Ukraine.  Won't be enough for 24/7 power in winter, but much easier/cheaper to maintain than generators and small ones cost less than €400 (excluding battery).

And of course, a critical question is whether giving up land for peace would actually work; this would require trusting the Putin regime to keep its word in a ceasefire agreement (or even peace treaty), and people would be forgiven for not having such trust.

@gerrit, the issue wouldn't just be retention of land, it would be a commitment to Ukrainian neutrality (i.e. political friendliness) towards Russia and exclusion of NATO. Those are fundamental points on which the war rests.

@Steve Yes, but a treaty only works if parties trust each other, and this trust will not be there as long as the Putin regime is in power.

@gerrit, war parties don't sign treaties on trust, they sign them when their interests align to stop fighting. If you're already anticipating that the treaty is going to be so harsh to one side or another that they will later want to renege, then it's not a treaty that will fly. Treaties that fly, are those which deliver continuing and indefinite value to both sides in abiding.

People are so used to Russia accepting awful terms on treaties so they can't wait for the behavior to resume.

@Steve on top of the value, trust is also important - when the other party is known to not respect their words, what is the point of signing anything? If there are ways that a party would benefit, they should just do it - if they can. A treaty assumes both parties give up something in exchange for something else, and if the other side is not trustworthy, you would not want to give up anything as it is going to be a waste.

@Mykola, the essence of what really forms and seals the treaty is the benefit to each side. The noting and signing is just ceremonial. Often the only thing that each side gives up, is the fighting, which by definition neither of them want to do anymore. If the situation changes and one side does want to resume fighting, then fighting resumes. Not all wars end in treaty - many end in a victory and a surrender, where the victor imposes the settlement as he pleases (so there isn't the question of trust or ongoing compliance).

@Steve: Interestingly, one of the longest-lasting cease fire treaties, between the US and England/Canada, includes a provision that either side may unilaterally annul it, without ever violating it, with thirty days notice.

@supercat, but what binds then from "violating" it, except the resumption of war? The choice of whether or not to continue abiding by the treaty is the choice a sovereign can make, and what binds them is their interest in compliance for the time being. When you're talking about whether you can "trust" the other side to comply, you're implicitly acknowledging that you don't think they actually have an interest in the treaty - and there's the problem with such a treaty. Liberals are scratching their heads about how they might force Russia to comply with a harmful treaty.

@Steve how drastic do you want to get? Political integration (i.e., merging Ukraine and Russia into one country) would end the war permanently, but for obvious reasons that's unacceptable to Ukraine.

@Allure, and war determines which side decides what is acceptable. You're presupposing the continued sovereign existence of Ukraine, who can take a view on what is acceptable to them or not. The outcome of wars can be that one state becomes a vassal state with fealty to the victor. Another outcome can be the complete dismissal of the separate existence of the weaker state administration, with land, assets, citizens, and culture absorbed. There are others, but my point is that the outcome of war is not necessarily one acceptable to both sides (and sometimes not acceptable to either side!).

@Steve For this war, yeah, that's probable. I suspect it's probable even in general, since most wars end with a victor and loser; relatively few end in draws.

@Steve: The Constitution of the United States specifies that treaties are subservient to the Constitution, but superior to everything else.  If Canada hadn't wanted the Great Lakes shipbuilders to build naval vessels during World War II to assist in the Allied war effort, such efforts would have been unlawful while the treaty was in effect, but the US would have the clear lawful authority to give Canada 30 days' notice that it was going to start building warships without any further notice or requests for permission, and that Canada would be free to nix the treaty altogether if it so chose.

@supercat, and what's to stop the US changing or overturning their constitution to make treaties subservient to more things, or to make treaties completely void? How will any other party in the world coerce the US for non-compliance with a treaty which it isn't in US interests to preserve anymore, except by winning war with the US?


By targeting civilians, Russia is deliberately violating international humanitarian law. It seeks in vain to break the morale of the Ukrainian nation. By indiscriminately striking cities, Russia seeks to terrorize. By destroying essential civilian infrastructure, especially in the energy sector, it intends to cause electricity and heating shortages with the onset of winter. It is counting on the suffering of civilians, including women, children and the elderly.

Permanent mission of France to the United Nations in New York
Russia's justifications revolve mostly around the fact that few civilian objects with significance beyond a doghouse would not have an indirect impact on the military as well.


I find it hard to believe that the general population of Ukraine would be seriously demoralised by occasional power cuts

Do you own a fridge at home, an AC unit perhaps? Have you ever been in a hospital during a power outage? Sure, by now practically every family in Ukraine owns a UPS or a generator, and so do hospitals and shops, but the very first strikes had serious impact on people.

I think I'd be more worried about my family at the fronts than the temperature inside the fridge.

@Steve It's not a dilemma. If there's no electricity at home, you have to worry about the fridge and your family is still at the fronts.

Yes but surely people have bigger things to worry about? A fridge going off unexpectedly when such an outage is rare, causes inconvenience and annoyance, but I cannot see how it leads to demoralisation amongst those who have elected to fight a lethal war for national independence. Even without the UPS or generator, during war you'd just buy fewer perishable things requiring refrigeration.

@Steve try feeding a baby with "fewer perishable things". There is no hard line between annoyance and demoralisation. Even in towns recently taken by Russia (which are essentially completely destroyed) there were a few people who chose not to flee. Most people found those conditions unliveable and evacuated though.
